# BASH - How to retrieve a single line from the file?

Tags: bash

How to retrieve a single line from the file?

```
file.txt
"aaaaaaa"
"bbbbbbb"
"ccccccc"
"ddddddd"
```

I need to retrieve the line 3 ("ccccccc")
Thank you.

Comment: How would the script/command select that line? Will you provide `3` as an argument to the script, or will you specify it otherwise? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I need to save it in a variable or used echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you need line 3, one approach is to use `head` to get the first three lines, and `tail` to get only the last of these:

```
varname="$(head -n 3 file.txt | tail -n 1)"
```

Another approach, using only Bash builtins, is to call `read` three times:

```
{ read ; read ; IFS= read -r varname } < file.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

`sed` is your friend. `sed -n 3p` prints the third line (`-n`: no automatic print, `3p`: print when line number is 3). You can also have much more complex patterns, for example `sed -n 3,10p` to print lines 3 to 10.

If the file is very big, you may consider to not cycle through the whole file, but quit after the print. `sed -n '3{p;q}'`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==3 {print; exit}' file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `awk '...'` : Invoke awk, a tool for manipulating files line-by-line. Instructions enclosed by single quotes are executed by awk.
- `FNR==3 {print; exit}`: FNR stands for "File Number Records"; just think of it as "number of lines read so far for this file". Here we are saying, if we are on the 3rd line of the file, print the entire line and then exit awk immediately so we don't waste time reading the rest of a large file.
- `file.txt`: specify the input file as an argument to awk to save a cat.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities: Try so:

```
sed '3!d' test
```

Here is a very fast version:

```
sed "1d; 2d; 3q"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are other tools than bash allowed?  On systems that include bash, you'll usually find `sed` and `awk` or other basic tools:

```
$ line="$(sed -ne 3p input.txt)"
$ echo "$line"
```

or

```
$ read line < <(awk 'NR==3' input.txt)
$ echo "$line"
```

or if you want to optimize this by quitting after the 3rd line is read:

```
$ read line < <(awk 'NR==3{print;nextfile}' input.txt)
$ echo "$line"
```

or how about even simpler tools (though less optimized):

```
$ line="`head -n 3 input.txt | tail -n 1`"
$ echo "$line"
```

Of course, if you really want to do this all within bash, you can still make it a one-liner, without using any external tools.

```
$ for (( i=3 ; i-- ; )); do read line; done < input.txt
$ echo "$line"
```

There are many ways to achieve the same thing.  Pick one that makes sense for your task.  Next time, perhaps explain your overall needs a bit better, so we can give you answers more applicable to your situation.

Comment: Note: `nextfile` requires GNU awk

Comment: Actually, nextfile also works in FreeBSD's awk, which I suspect means it's also portable to OSX.  But a good point in general; if `nextfile` isn't available, it may be possible to simply `exit` with similar effect.

Comment: I think `exit` is the more straightforward command to use here, regardless of awk version.

Comment: You're right, it is.  I guess I'm just in the habit of using `nextfile`.  Anyway, I like the last (bash-only) solution the best.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Since, as usual, all the other answers involve trivial and usual stuff (pipe through `grep` then `awk` then `sed` then `cut` or `you-name-it`), here's a very unusual and (sadly) not very well-known one (so, I hereby claim that I have the most original answer):

```
mapfile -s2 -n3 -t < input.txt
echo "$MAPFILE"
```

I would say this is fairly efficient (`mapfile` is quite efficient and it's a bash builtin).

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Fast bash version;

```
while (( ${i:-1} <= 3 )); do
  (( $i == 3 )) && read -r line; (( i++ ))
done < file.txt
```

**Output**

```
echo "$line" # Third line
"ccccccc"
```

**Explanation**

- `while (( ${i:-1} <= 3 ))` - Count until `$i` equals `3` then exit loop.
- `(( $i == 3 ))` - If `$i` is equal to `3` execute read line.
- `read -r line` - Read the file line into variable `$line`.
- `(( i++ ))` - Increment `$i` by `1` at each loop.
- `done < file.txt` - Pipe file into while loop.